# Error getting store metadata via NSPersistentStore class method

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I’m exploring Core Data custom migration, for which I need to run a test on the existing store to see whether it is compatible with the currently loaded mom. And to do that, I need to get the metadata from the store.

So I do this in the AppDelegate class:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *applicationSupportDirectory = [self applicationSupportDirectory];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [applicationSupportDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"sharedPersistMainStore.sqlite"]];
NSDictionary *storeMetadata = [NSPersistentStore metadataForPersistentStoreWithURL:url error:&error];
```

But I get this error:

> metadataForPersistentStoreWithURL:error: cannot be sent to an abstract object of class
>   NSPersistentStore: Create a concrete instance!

Which sounds like they’re telling me to use this as an instance method. But the API definitely lists it as a class method.

Odder still, calling this (deprecated) method works as expected:

```
NSDictionary *storeMetadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreWithURL:url error:&error];
```

Except for a warning that it is a deprecated method.

Any ideas what’s going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass [NSAtomicStore](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSAtomicStore_class/Reference/NSAtomicStore.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSAtomicStore) in order to use that method

Comment: Oh, OK. Checking out NSAtomicStore, I see it’s a subclass of NSPersistentStore. And I see now that in the NSPersistentStore Overview, they do announce: “This class is the abstract base class for all Core Data persistent stores.”

Further hunting shows that, since I’m using an sqlite store, not an NSAtomicStore, what I really should have done was:
<code>

 NSDictionary *storeMetadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
  metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:NSSQLiteStoreType URL:url error:&error];
</code>

It works!

Thanks for the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

`NSPersistentStore` is an abstract class, you are calling an unimplemented class method. To get the metadata for a store, you must first register it with a persistent store coordinator, then query the coordinator for the store either using `NSPersistentStoreCoodinator`'s`+ metadataForPersistentStoreWithURL:error` or:

```
NSPersistentStore *store = [coordinator persistentStoreForURL:url];
NSDictionary *storeMetadata = [[store metadata] copy];
```